# SQLite UPDATE WHERE query

Tags: sql, sqlite, sql-update

Hi guys new here need some help with SQLite. I'm trying to update some records based on other records and I'm doing something wrong. 
This is the table:
Id, comment, userscore, verification, flagIncorrect, flagCorrect. 
This is the code:

```
UPDATE comments 
  SET userscore=userscore+50, verification=1
Where id=1, verification=0;
```

Comment: Hint:  `AND` or `OR`.

Comment: where id=1 **and** verification=0

Comment: Wow that was fast!

Comment: Thanx a lot btw

Comment: For your next question please consider: Explain what makes you think that "I'm doing something wrong" and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Sorry ill try to explain better next time, english is my 2nd language :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a condition "AND" or "OR" in your **WHERE** clause instead of the comma.

```
UPDATE
   comments
SET
   userscore=userscore+50,
   verification=1
WHERE
   id=1 AND --could also be OR
   verification=0
;
```